# ssh'ing from a machine I've ssh'ed into

Tags: ssh, git

I'm trying to ssh into a machine (let's call it `B`) from a machine (let's call it `A`), and then run a command on that machine (`B`) that would usually require entering an ssh passphrase (if you're interested, I'm trying to `git pull` from a private repository on BitBucket).

I can ssh into `B` from `A` (without entering a passphrase), and can run commands on that machine, like this:

```
A > ssh B 'ls'
```

I can also ssh into `B` from `A`, and run my `git pull`, and it asks for a passphrase:

```
A > ssh B
B > git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

However, if I try a git pull (which would require a passphrase), this happens:

```
A > ssh cbc 'git pull'
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any idea how I can get `git pull` working without a passphrase from `A` on `B`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up `ssh-agent` (or equivalent), then enable *agent forwarding* for SSH connections.

### Enable ssh-agent on your local machine

"Local" being the one you're sitting at. You should not need to run the agent anywhere else.

If you're lucky, one will be already running; most Linux distributions start an instance for every X11 session. Run `ssh-add` to import your keys; `ssh-add -l` to list keys.

If using GNOME or Mac OS X, you will probably have their own agent implementation, which imports known keys on login. With the standard OpenSSH `ssh-agent`, though, you have to do this manually (although scripts and PAM modules exist to automate).

On Windows, PuTTY comes with *Pageant*, and Cygwin OpenSSH with the same `ssh-agent` (although much more complicated to use than in Unix).

### Enable agent forwarding

Once you have the agent working and keys loaded, try to connect like this:

```
A> ssh-add -l

A> ssh -A B ssh-add -l
```

The `-A` option enables agent forwarding over the SSH connection, so if everything works right, both commands above should give identical output.

```
$ ssh-add -l
2048 06:b7:29:1e:6b:ea:c3:04:c4:33:fc:48:e0:62:2f:ef grawity@anywhere (old key) (RSA)
4096 19:3c:f0:79:32:00:fa:04:2f:15:5d:2a:e2:c9:a3:ad grawity@anywhere (2011-11-01) (RSA)

$ ssh panther ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

$ ssh -A panther ssh-add -l
2048 06:b7:29:1e:6b:ea:c3:04:c4:33:fc:48:e0:62:2f:ef grawity@anywhere (old key) (RSA)
4096 19:3c:f0:79:32:00:fa:04:2f:15:5d:2a:e2:c9:a3:ad grawity@anywhere (2011-11-01) (RSA)
```

If it works, make it persistent by editing `~/.ssh/config` – put this at the bottom:

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Instead of `*` you can give a list of trusted names; see manual page of `ssh_config` for exact syntax.

You can enable forwarding on *all* machines; there is no limit to how much you can chain.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks! Everything worked first time (except when I typed `ssh -A B` without thinking to substitute the real hostname...).